# tag a friend on a wall post android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to send a wall post to facebook and tag one of my friend via graph api. I have my friends facebook ID. where should I write his/her Id to be able to tag him/her in my wall post?

```
params.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
params.putString("Message","I m here");

String response = facebook.request("me/feed", params, "POST");
```

Thanks for your helps

Comment: @ user1448565 I am also looking for the same. did you get solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Comma-separated list of Facebook IDs of people tagged in this Post. For example: 1207059,701732. This field is returned as the with_tags field when the Post is read.

### NOTE: You cannot specify this field without also specifying a place.

Where place is :- Facebook Page ID of the location associated with this Post

### Check this:-

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Comment: please provide the code for reference..how to tag the friends..what to write in the key value pair of the putString method of the bundle.

Answer (score 3):

1) Create a String array of friends id and pass it to .request() method

```
for(int j=0;j<numArr.length;j++)
{
   Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("Photo_id/tags/"+numArr[j], param, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in your code, just add:

```
params.putString("place", "155021662189");
```

Use "155021662189" if you don't know any FB placeId.
In my application, this worked.

Reference: http://codenigeria.com/discussion/245/facebook-api-how-to-make-status-update-on-facebook-but-also-tag-some-facebook-friends-in-it-/p1

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the graph api: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

message_tags can be used to tag anything

Comment: params.putString("message_tags",userIdOfFriend); I did this when I am sending my message but it is now shown on my wall. It shows only "I am here"

Comment: The parameter is called __tags__ – see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Comment: Getting this error when I use tags. I don't want to do checkin, I want to only tag a friend on a wallpost.

{"error":{"message":"(#100) Cannot specify user tags without a place tag","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}